# Sufficient conditions for finite mean of a non-negative random variable

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration

Consider a continuous random variable that takes only non-negative values. Let the cumulative distribution function be $F(\cdot)$. Consider the following condition:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x(1-F(x))=0.$$
Is it sufficient for the mean to be finite? If not, is there any other sufficient condition for the finite mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[Recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13377/55451) that $E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx$.  So this shows that something like $F(x) = 1-1/(x \log x)$ for large $x$ is a counterexample.

This does however show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^p (1-F(x)) = 0$ for some $p>1$ would suffice.